# Painless Web Hosting - Migration of existing servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, migration

I have 2 VPS servers (windows server 2008 R2) where I have hosted web sites and applications. Earlier we had it on dedicated server. But later we migrated to VPS servers. Each time we migrated we manually copied all the required files into the servers, installed IIS web servers, installed the .net frameworks and all other required settings manually for all our web services, windows services and web sites to run successfully.

But to do this manually, it is time consuming and a tedious job.

I would like to know if there is any other way which would help me clone my server on a different VPS or do all the above tasks automatically helping me set up a server in minutes.

This should include setting up web server and do all the settings on the IIS for the website to be up in minutes.

Also want to know about auto scaling options when there is more traffic to our web site?

I know that Amazon EC2 instances can do this but i want to know if there are any other alternatives for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of managing this is to treat your website as an application and have a proper build/deploy process for it. This way you have an installation routing (perhaps controlled by a powershell script or similar) that puts your files into the right locations and configures IIS (see http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell for examples of that).

This way your site/application can be installed on a new server very easily: just pull the latest stable version from source control, drop it into a temporary area on the server, and run the install script.

Once that is done all you need to do is copy over any variable data: databases and so forth that contain user provided information. You may even be able to automate that as an optional part of the install process.

Comment: can you please provide me with some basic steps? im very new to this. also i need to know of some autoscaling options.